# no instance of constructor matches the argument list, but I am passing in a nullptr to a constructor that takes a pointer and a default value

Tags: c++, constructor

We have to create a polynomial class for homework, and I've just started writing mine.

My error is occuring in my implementation/.cpp file in the List default constructor. Specifically, the error reads

> no instance of constructor "Polynomial::List::Node::Node" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::nullptr_t)

This is my header file

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL
#define POLYNOMIAL

#include <vector>

class Polynomial {
public:
    Polynomial(); 
    Polynomial(std::vector<int>);
private:
    class List {
    public:
        List();
        void addToEnd(int); 
    private:
        struct Node {
            Node(Node*, int = 0);
            Node* next;
            int coefficient;
        }; 
        Node* head; 
        Node* last_node; 
    };
    List coefficients; 
    int degree; 
};

#endif
```

This is my implementation file

```
#include "polynomial.hpp"
using namespace std; 

// Polynomial Constructors/Methods

Polynomial::Polynomial() : coefficients(), degree(0) {}

Polynomial::Polynomial(vector<int> coefficients) {}


// List constructors/Methods

Polynomial::List::List() : 
head(new Node(nullptr)) {} // error (as described in title) is happening on this line


// Node constructors/Methods
Polynomial::List::Node::Node(Node* next, int coefficient) 
: next(next), coefficient(coefficient) {}
```

I have a feeling this problem has to do with not qualifying my constructors properly in my .cpp file, as I'm not sure what else the problem could be.

However, I've tried writing the problem line as such but I get the same problem:

```
head(new Polynomial::List::Node(nullptr)) {}
```

I know there are tons of questions similar to mine on StackOverflow already, but the other problems I've found occur because people are missing constructors entirely, or the constructors they use take arguments different to what they are passed. As far as I can tell, I'm using the Node struct's constructor appropriately.

**EDIT**: I've been told that this compiled fine on someone else's system. Also, my error is in the form of a red squiggle that occurred without me having to compile. I assumed this meant I had a compilation error that VS code "caught early", but I don't know how true that is. Perhaps I have an issue with my VS Code configuration, or the C++ extension I'm using?

Comment: Question -- if you're able to use `std::vector`, why not use `std::list` instead of the `List` class?

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point. It didn't occur to me that we might be allowed to skip implementing the List ourselves but I'll look into it. Either way, I have no idea what's wrong with my code as is.

Comment: The provided code compiles for me with no warnings or errors.

Comment: Huh? I wonder if that means it's a bug with the VS Code extension I am using?

Comment: Make sure it really is a compiler error and not intellisense barfing.

Comment: Red squiggles may mean something or may not. If in doubt try to compile your program. Either you get compiler complaints (the only thing you really can trust) or your found a weakness of your syntax checker. (It wouldn't be the first one. These syntax checkers are not that bad meanwhile but C++ is a damn complicated language concerning the compiler.) In my brand-new and up-to-date Visual Studio 2019, I often noticed that unexpected red squiggles of Intellisense vanished in the moment where I compiled... ;-)

Comment: @joshblech If you're using Visual Studio, all compiler errors have a code starting with `C`, for example `C4321`.  If you don't see the code, then it isn't an error -- it is probably, as others mentioned, an Intellisense warning, either false or maybe justified.

Comment: Think of intellisense as a really fast compiler. It has to be fast or it'll slow you down when you're working, but to make it fast, some imperfections need to be accepted. It is not 100% accurate. The hit-miss ratio is pretty good, so overall it is a helpful tool.

Comment: *"this compiled fine on someone else's system"* -- while technically true, you might have jumped to an incorrect conclusion. I did not compile your code on *my* system, but on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/). I sometimes suggest using an online compiler (Wandbox is not the only one) to confirm that example code replicates a problem, but when it comes to Intellisense, actual compilation should be enough to confirm/deny red squiggles you do not understand (as others have mentioned).